# Is it possible to use literals like ⊥ outside of math mode?

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode

I have a .tex file that I'm compiling with luatex that I would like to
be able to use a utf-8 literal in. Using unicode-math, it's possible
to use the literal inside of math mode as such:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$⊥ \bot$
\end{document}
```

Is there a font or is it otherwise possible to just have an uptack as a utf-8 character?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can, if the text font supports the symbol.

Comment: you have to load fontspec and the font has to provide the symbol. Most non-mathfonts do not provide this symbol.

Comment: What's wrong in using `$⊥$` when you need the symbol?

Comment: There is a one markdown file that is being translated to html with `rustdoc` and to tex with `pandoc` and subsequently pdf with `luatex`. Rustdoc does not recognize `$\bot$` and leaves it alone, so it would be preferable to just have the character `⊥` in each file.

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial solution with adding

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar⊥{{$\bot$}}
```

This is somewhat unsatisfactory, because it requires an addition for each symbol desired.

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing else to do: if the font you use doesn't have the glyph, some substitution has to be performed. There's a useless pair of braces in your code and you might do `\newunicodechar{⊥}{\ensuremath{\bot}}` so the symbol won't give errors if used in math mode.